# Visual studio 2015 severely misbehave if I change the language setting. Solutions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I just stumbled across this really weird bug. My Visual Studio was set to the OS language (italian),I changed it to be english,restarted it, but now every time I run my code the compiler just run some code it had stored somewhere,even if I had deleted said code from my project. Every update to my main.cpp get completely ignored by the compiler and just runs the old code each time I ask to compile.

Not only that,if I attempt to create a new project,select c++ "win32 console project", hit the "New" button,instead of creating the new project it close the project creation window for half a second and then prompt me back into it again. I can hit New even 10 times and nothings changes,I get stuck into a loop that prompts me to the same project creation window again and again,without nothing being created.

On the other hand,if I change back the interface language to italian, all the problem are fixed and it works as supposed.

Any idea what's going on here and how do I fix it? I would like to run it english, of course.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your system?  (Clutching at straws here).

Comment: @MartinBonner yes I did,and I am also running VS as admin

Comment: though I got to say,I installed the english lang pack with normal rights,now I try to run that a second time as admin to see if somehow fix it

Comment: it actually gave an error at the end,translating from italian said: impossible to find SQL server compact path ...or something like that...so I bet is related to the bug